# While editing a script, how many UNDO and REDO levels can I have and what rests that number?

Tags: undo-redo, google-apps-script-editor

Most answers here are discussing the UNDO/REDO of changes to something made by a script.
I am noticing that I can only go back so many times, through edits I have been making to my script.

How many levels back can I go?
Can I increase this number?
What things reset the UNDO's?

PS> I know I can go back in Versions, but that seems to be for the Project as a whole, and I just want to have unlimited undos for the script I am working on.

UNDO and REDO work but have limits.

Expected to be able to keep going back.

Comment: Undocumented. Likely a function of the current editor UI implementation, perhaps also your browser.

Comment: UI I could imagine, could impact this, but is there not info on the basic function of the default Script Editor associated with Google Sheets Script Editor?

Comment: No, I don't see why Google would waste their time documenting minutiae like the size of the Undo/Redo stack either. It's a simple web editor - if you want a more established environment you can use [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp) and an IDE of your choice to manipulate your Apps Script projects

Comment: Thanx for the comment. Although not really an answer, it allowed me to stop looking for the answer.  I also, appreciate your suggestion that I might want to use another Editor.  Shoudl I mark this as Answered?